# Form keeps current state when resetting form (React-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm building a filter form using react-hook-form. I have a main component which will render a list of users. The component has a filters state which keeps the active filters.

A second component is used to render the form with the different filters. The `filters` state is passed down to this component to fill in the form with the current values and to display a list of active filters and to option to remove or clear them all.

I expect that the form resets when all filters are cleared or a form field resets when an active filter is removed. Both are not working at this point and I can't figure out why.

I have made a small demo which can be found over here: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mcsgpn?file=src%2FApp.tsx)
Expected behaviour for the demo: Press the filters button. Press 'Clear filters'. The active filters should be empty and the form should be reseted which should result in 'status' having an `undefined` value and the select box showing 'Select an option'.

Some relevant code blocks:

**App.tsx**

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState<UserFilters>({
    status: 'active',
});

const onClearFilters = () => {
    setFilters({});
};

const onRemoveFilter = (key: keyof UserFilters) => {
    const newFilters = { ...filters };
    delete newFilters[key];
    setFilters(newFilters);
};

return (
    <UserFilterForm
        filters={filters}
        applyFilters={setFilters}
        removeFilter={onRemoveFilter}
        clearFilters={onClearFilters}
    />
)
```

**UserFilterForm.tsx**

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm<UserFilters>({
    defaultValues: filters,
});


useEffect(() => {
    reset(filters);
}, [filters]);

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onApplyFilters)}>
        <fieldset className='space-y-6'>
            <Controller
                name='status'
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <SelectField
                        id='status'
                        label='Status'
                        onChange={onChange}
                        value={value}
                        options={statusOptions}
                        error={errors?.status?.message as string}
                    />
                )}
            />

            <Button type='submit' width='full'>
                Apply filters
            </Button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
);
```